# Spark mllib Collaborative Filtering, ValueError: RDD is empty

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm new to Spark and am running the implicit collaborative fitering from here [mllib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html).  When I run the following code on my data, I'm getting the following error:

```
 ValueError: RDD is empty
```

Here is my data:

```
 101,1000010,1
 101,1000011,1
 101,1000015,1
 101,1000017,1
 101,1000019,1
 102,1000010,1
 102,1000012,1
 102,1000019,1
 103,1000011,1
 103,1000012,1
 103,1000013,1
 103,1000014,1
 103,1000017,1
 104,1000010,1
 104,1000012,1
 104,1000013,1
 104,1000014,1
 104,1000015,1
 104,1000016,1
 104,1000017,1
 105,1000017,1
```

And my code:

```
 from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
 data = sc.textFile("s3://xxxxxxxxxxxx.csv")

 ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
.map(lambda l: Rating(l[0], l[1], float(l[2])))

 # Build the recommendation model using Alternating Least Squares
 rank = 10
 numIterations = 10
 alpha = 0.01
 model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, alpha)

 # Evaluate the model on training data
 testdata = ratings.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1]))
 predictions = model.predictAll(testdata).map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2]))
 ratesAndPreds = ratings.map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2])).join(predictions)
 # convert pyspark pipeline to DF
 ratesAndPreds.toDF().show()
```

Comment: So, one of the RDD is empty. Do you know if it comes from data, ratings, testdata, predictions or ratesAndPreds ?

Comment: Umm, just check every step, print data, ratings etc, see where is empty.